# What is the propertyname for obtaining file size during file transfer in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

What is the propertyname for obtaining the file size during file transfer in **WSO2 ESB**?  Is below code the way to get file name?

```
get-property('transport', 'FILE_PATH')?
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file name : get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')

file size : get-property('transport', 'FILE_LENGTH')

last modification date : get-property('transport', 'LAST_MODIFIED')